# Bash script to rename a heap of folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rename, strip

I have a directory that looks a little like this:

```
drw-r--r-- 1 root   root     0 Jan 24 17:26 -=1=-directoryname
drw-r--r-- 1 root   root     0 Jan 24 17:26 -=2=-directoryname
drw-r--r-- 1 root   root     0 Jan 24 17:26 -=3=-directoryname
drw-r--r-- 1 root   root     0 Jan 24 17:26 -=4=-directoryname
drw-r--r-- 1 root   root     0 Jan 24 17:26 -=5=-directoryname
```

I am trying to write a script to change these folders from
`-=1=- Folder#1`
to strip off the "`-=1=-`" section, but alas I am having no luck.

Can anyone help me find a solution to this?

So far my script below has failed me.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..250}
do
        rename "-=$i=-" ""*
        i=i+1
done
```

I have used the 1..250 because there are 250 folders.

Comment: Is the `rename` command you've got the Perl based one or the rather simpler C program?

Comment: Updated the question, the directory name is not identified by a number after stripping the beginning section. I have the pearl version of rename.

Comment: Now you've got a different problem; is the directory name part always the same?  You should show `-=1=-directoryname` and `-=2=-nameofdirectory` and `-=3=-directory` and `-=4=-name` or other similar differences to make it clearer what you're dealing with.  If you have the Perl `rename` (no 'a' in Perl), then my answer can be be adapted; you simply change the glob to `-=*=-*`, for example.  If there's no space, drop the space from the `s///` command regex.  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the number, you can manufacture the names and use the `mv` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..250}
do
    mv "-=$i=- Folder#$i" "Folder#$i"
done
```

With the Perl-based `rename` command (sometimes called `prename`), you could use:

```
rename 's/-=\d+=- //' -=*=-*Folder#*
```

or, given the revised question (the information after the pattern isn't fixed):

```
rename 's/-=\d+=- //' -=*=-*
```

> This worked! Can you please explain how it worked? What's the `\d+` for?

The `\d` is Perl regex notation for a digit `0`..`9`.  The `+` modifier indicates 'one or more'.  So, the regex part of `s/-=\d+=- //` looks for a minus, an equals, one or more digits, an equals, a minus and a space.  The replace part converts all of the matched material into an empty string.  It's all surrounded by single quotes so the shell leaves it alone (though there's only the backslash that's a shell metacharacter in that substitute command, but the backslash and space would need protecting if you omitted the quotes).

---

I'm not sure how you'd use the C-based `rename` command for this job; it is much less powerful than the Perl-based version.

Comment: rename 's/-=\d+=- //' -=*=-*     This worked! can you please explain how it worked? whats the \d+ for?